# What diagram I should use to represent interaction between functions in modules?

Tags: c, uml, diagram, sysml

I need  to create a diagram using UML or SysML notation. I've got  modules, that consists of functions. Some functions are used only “inside” the module, others are used by other modules.

Example:

`MODULE 1` has two functions: `func1` and `func2`. `func2` uses `func1`:

```
int func1 (int p1, int p2)
{
   d=func1();
   return noerr;
}

int func2 (int p3, int p4)
{
    if (p4>0 || func1(p1,p2))
    {
        // warning
    }
    else
    {
        return noerr;
    }
}
```

`MODULE 2` has one function, `func3`. It uses  `func1` from `MODULE 1`:

```
int func3 (int p5, int p6)
{
    if (p5<0 || func1(p1,p2))
    {
        // warning
    }
    else
    {
        return noerr;
    }
}
```

I need to show graphically interaction between `func1` and `func2` inside `MODULE 1` and interaction between `MODULE 1` and `MODULE 2`  with use of `func1`. I'll appreciate any help and samples.

Comment: func1 will loop forever :-)

Answer (score 6):

In UML, I would regard the modules as classes and the functions as operations of these classes, as in the following **class diagram**:

[image: classd]

The dependencies at the function level and the interaction between the modules can be depicted using **sequence diagrams** as follows:

[image: seq1]

[image: seq2]

Comment: Thank You so much! I thought about that too. But the problem is that those diagrams shows only interactions for "control" flows and does not represent "data" flows. Is it possible to show also data flows using this views without creating additional diags?

Comment: You may insert the parameter names and values in between the brackets and you may display reply messages (dashed arrows from callee to caller) with the data returned as text near those arrows. See Figure 2 of http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html#N100A4

Comment: Depends on what you define as "data". The messages take parameters (above they are just empty brackets). These parameters can well be seen as data. (Hehe. Cross-posting ;-)